# Using compare and read/write operations for std::atomic<bool> in c++?

Tags: c++, c++11

Assume there are `2` threads as `threadA` and `threadB` and we're gonna using of a `std::atomic<bool>` data-type in these `threads`. So now we have some critical sections as bellow:

**My global variable (threads access to it concurrently) :**

```
std::atomic<bool> flag;
```

**threadA :**

```
void *threadA(void *arg)
{
    bool ttt = true;
    if(flag == true)                   // comparison operator ==
        // do something

    // something to do
    flag = false;                      // assign a avalue
    ttt = flag;                        // read operation

    return 0;
}
```

**threadB :**

```
void *threadB(void *arg)
{
    bool m = true;
    if(flag == true)                   // comparison operator ==
        flag = false;

    // something to do
    flag = true;                       // assign a value
    m = !flag;                         // read operation

    return 0;
}
```

Any way, i know `std::atomic<>` unlike ordinary data-types are free-races, but i wanna be sure about these :

- will be any trouble when using of `==`, `assignment`, `read/write` instead of (for example) `std::atomic_load` or exchange statements?
- is it possible to occur any trouble, something like `memory` problems while read or write of `flag`?
- is it absolutely safe in any platform with any *CPU* architecture? I mean(a portable code). because `atomic<bool>` not need in some *X86* architectures?

i just wanna use of `atomic` feature instead of `mutex`.

Comment: Your code simply won't work, because *compare and assign* in second function is not atomic. Any order is possible for your "do something".

Comment: @liliscent sorry, i did not get you, what do you mean about second function exactly?

Comment: Your code is safe, in the sense that it doesn't contain a data race (unless there's some other shared data hidden behind all those `do something`). E.g. `std::atomic::operator=` works the same as `store()`. That said, the games you play with `flag` make no sense - it's not at all clear what this random-looking sequence of assignments and comparisons is supposed to achieve.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik i know this is a random-looking without any particular purpose, but i just tell about `atomic`. so regardless of contain, is `atomic` safe as the `mutex`?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Concurrent access to an `atomic` object from multiple threads does not give rise to a data race, if that's what you are asking.

Comment: The answer to the question about `std::atomic` is not useful, because you're using a very low-level primitive to implement some sort of synchronization between threads. This is surprisingly hard to get right. Please modify the question to explain what exactly you're trying to achieve. For example, if you were to protect access to a shared resource, you'd use `QMutex/QMutexLocker` or `QReadWriteLock/QReadLocker/QWriteLocker`. If you were implementing a producer-consumer, you'd wish to consider futures and their [promise-like adapter `asyncfuture`](https://github.com/benlau/asyncfuture).

Answer (score 1):

> will be any trouble when using of `==`, `assignment`, `read/write` instead of (for example) `std::atomic_load` or `exchange` statements?

When `operator==` is used with `std::atomic<T>` and `T`, it first invokes `atomic<T>::operator T()` to `load` the atomic value using the strongest memory ordering `std::memory_order_seq_cst`. Next, `operator==(T, T)` is used. This sequence is not atomic. Which means that when the comparison actually happens that `std::atomic<T>` may have already changed.

> just wanna use of atomic feature instead of `mutex`.

You can implement a spin-lock with an atomic using [std::atomic::compare_exchange_weak](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/compare_exchange) (there is an example), but it won't be able to put the thread to sleep like `std::mutex` does.